# Menu Structure options disappear after updating beyond WP 4.0

Tags: javascript, wordpress, menu

If I update to any Wordpress version beyond 4.0 I can no longer see my Menu Structure options. The Screen Options & Help tabs don't pull down either, but other tabs work. I've tried all of the usual...disabled plugins, etc.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you open up the javascript console and share which errors you see? Just google how to open it for your browser.

Comment: I'm seeing one error... looks like some sort of jquery error? It's on line 83 in nav-menus.php so I'm guessing this is the problem.

Screenshot: http://atmarkdesign.com/images/error.jpg

Ideas?

Comment: does this apply to you? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/menu-doesnt-load-columns-not-defined-in-load-scriptsphp/ You said so you tried it without plugins, so maybe it is this problem instead https://wordpress.org/support/topic/upgrade-breaks-menu-admin/